# Gwt and native html inter play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gwt

I have a bunch of native html elements from a bootstrap template - namely cleanzone.

I would like to handle the events fired from the html directly in my gwt app with or without wrapping the html elements as gwt widgets.

e.g.

```
<div id=avatar class=".gwt-Image">
    <img src=avatar6.jpg></img>
</div>
```

I tried wrapping this in a Image widget by using code -

```
Element ele = RootPanel.get("avatar").getElement() ;
Image.wrap(ele)
```

I also tried

```
final Element element = DOM.getElementById("avatar");
final Image img = Image.wrap(element);
```

In both cases it throws an exception. My Question is

--- Since I will do all my styling using css is it necessary to wrap the html tag in the page as a gwt widget to handle events fired by it and if yes what is the best approach to wrap a huge number of widgets on my page i.e. almost all of it from cleanzone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just catch an event you can do these things:

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onPreviewNativeEvent(Event.NativePreviewEvent nativePreviewEvent) {
      // catch event                 
   }
});

DOM.sinkEvent(element, Event.ONCLICK);
```